# THREE.js issue with intersecting objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, intersection

I'm having an issue detecting object intersections with THREE.js.  My objects are being extruded from a 2D geometry like such:

```
var geoShape = new THREE.Shape(vertexes);
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(geoShape, { bevelEnabled: false, amount: 3 });

var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry,
    [new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: '#493D26' })]
);
scene.add(mesh);
```

I am then trying to detect intersection like this:

```
container.mousedown(function (e) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

    console.log(intersects);
});
```

Everytime, my intersects array is empty.  If I add a sphere to the scene, I get intersections, but only if I am zoomed in to z < 18.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your canvas element is full screen?

Comment: @uhura At the moment, yes.  I'll probably change that later, but I can deal with that when I come to it.

Comment: Try to add true to  `raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);`

Comment: @uhura Holy heck, was it really that easy?  That worked like a charm.  Move it to an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add true

```
raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
```

From Docs:

> recursive (true) — If set, it also checks all descendants. Otherwise
>   it only checks intersecton with the object.

Answer (score 3):

Several things can be causing the raycaster not to be build up properly, the best way to debug it and to be sure your raycaster is the right one I recommend you to visualize it using: raycaster.ray.origin and raycaster.ray.direction, the line can be drawn easily like this in the same mouse event that should detect the intersection:

```
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
});
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(raycaster.ray.origin.x, raycaster.ray.origin.y, raycaster.ray.origin.z));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(raycaster.ray.origin.x + (raycaster.ray.direction.x * 100000), raycaster.ray.origin.y + (raycaster.ray.direction.y * 100000), raycaster.ray.origin.z + (raycaster.ray.direction.z * 100000)));
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
```

NOTE: Take into account that the ray will be visualized just if the camera point of view is changed!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was uhura's answer...

```
raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
```

... **PLUS** the realization that the the raycaster ***generates an array of all intersections***, not just the first one. My code was iterating through all intersections and displaying the last one, when I wanted the first one only. So...

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true);

if(intersects.length > 0)
{
//Do something with intersects[0];
}
```